# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES alternative in 5.7? More info about show_compatibility_56

Tags: mysql, information-schema

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_VARIABLES;
ERROR 3167 (HY000): The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES' feature is disabled; see the documentation for 'show_compatibility_56'

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.10    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.global_variables' doesn't exist
```

I googled that and found links to tocker.ca which seems down.

```
$ curl  http://www.tocker.ca/2015/08/18/a-followup-on-show_compatibility_56.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /2015/08/18/a-followup-on-show_compatibility_56.html was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Where do I see what settings/variables have changed from default one (in my setup)?

Any background about this change?

Comment: The current accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219433/470749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`.

See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-startup-configuration.html) for details:

> The Performance Schema is disabled by default. To enable it, start the
>   server with the performance_schema variable enabled. For example, use
>   these lines in your my.cnf file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld] 
> performance_schema=ON
> ```

*Please check updated syntax from mysql website

[Migrating to Performance Schema System and Status Variable Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html) has all the information you'd ever need on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong answer. Performance schema has nothing to do with information schema.
The reason you get an error related to GLOBAL_VARIABLES which is in information is due to compatibility with 5.6 ;

mysql> show variables like '%show_compatibility_56%' ;
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| show_compatibility_56 | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> set global show_compatibility_56=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%show_compatibility_56%' ;
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| show_compatibility_56 | ON    |
+-----------------------+-------+